# Next.js development server automatically stopping

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It just automatically stops, I tried different ports, restarting my PC nothing worked.

Console Output:
D:\project>npm run dev

> project@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

D:\project>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue starting a new project. Next v13. Node v18.14.1.

The solution was to:

- Go to the [Node js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download) and download and install version [18.15.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.15.0/node-v18.15.0-x64.msi) (however, later versions like 18.17.1 should also work).
- Restart VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, (as elaboration to this issue **NextJs dev server was crashing as soon as the instance is opened on the browser or even before that**) and found out that in my case I accidentally upgraded my NodeJs version to 32bit architecture,

**Re-Installing the node with 64bit architecture** resolved my issue but you must restart your system or restart IDE instances, to continue ...

**Note: I was using NextJs version 13.x**